# Trying to display image in Laravel 5.1 using dropzone

Tags: mysql, image, laravel, laravel-5.1, dropzone.js

I am trying to display the image from the file path but it's seeing a different thing entirely, I'm vague of what to do. I am using dropzone. The images are stored in this directory `laravel/public/gallery/images`. so the url is thus: `http://localhost:port/gallery/images`. The images are saved in the db successfully but displaying them is an issue. This is the code to display:

```
<TR><TD>

                    <DIV class="row">
                      <DIV class="col-md-12">
                        <DIV id="gallery-images">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach($productVerificationValidation->productDocumentUpload as $productDocument)
                                  <li>
                                      <a href="{{url($productDocument->file_path)}}./.{{$productDocument->file_name}}" target="_blank">
                                        <img src="{{url($productDocument->file_path)}}">
                                      </a>
                                  </li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </DIV>
                      </DIV>
                    </DIV>

                  </TD></TR>
```

This is the controller to display the view:

```
   public function viewUploadedDocuments($id=null){
            $productVerificationValidation = ProductVerificationValidation::findOrFail($id);
            return view('product.verification-validation.viewDocuments')->with('productVerificationValidation', $productVerificationValidation);
}
```

To my surprise when i check the console on Chrome, instead of getting the properties of the images it returns wrong properties as displayed on the screenshot:
[image: wrong properties assigned to an image]
but the db record has a different property as displayed on the screenshot:
[image: db properties different from what's displayed on console.]
what wrong am I to make right, Please help out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I got it working by appending the file name to it thus:

```
<DIV class="row">
                      <DIV class="col-md-12">
                        <DIV id="gallery-images">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach($productVerificationValidation->productDocumentUpload as $productDocument)
                                  <li>
                                      <a href="{{url($productDocument->file_path .'/'. $productDocument->file_name)}}" target="_blank">
                                        <img src="{{ url($productDocument->file_path .'/'. $productDocument->file_name) }}" />
                                      </a>
                                  </li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </DIV>
                      </DIV>
                    </DIV>
```